# Split strings from text file into string arrays

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm solving a problem, which gets an array of strings from a .txt file, which contains the first and last name of a person. The problem is that when I try to split the elements from the string "line" and try to give other two strings those values, it doesn't work.

The text file contains:

```
Noah Mason  
Emma Williams  
Richard Daniel
and so on...
```

I want to split the lines into two separate string arrays "firstName" and "secondName". And I want something like this:

```
firstName[0]="Noah";  
firstName[1]="Emma";  
firstName[2]="Richard";  
secondName[0]="Mason";  
secondName[1]="Williams";  
secondName[2]="Daniel";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you getting? What is the "something" that happens? Is there something in the language you don't understand? In short, put more effort and detail into your question. This is a simple problem to solve but I doubt the contributors here will write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

To read text from text file and storing the  data in array you can follow this approach

```
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) { String line; while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String[] name = line.split(" ");
//Save the name array in any global array variable.} }
```